# how to verify the P7b Certificate against the trust chain using openssl?

Tags: certificate, openssl, x509certificate, verification, truststore

can any one tell me how to verify the P7b container (which have three different files )against the CA Certificates available in "/home/user/Certificate/" folder(includes the intermediate certificates) using openssl.

i have 5 different Root certificates and each have 3 intermediate Certificates.

Comment: Please check if PKCS7_verify can help you. However, before calling the function, you need to add the certificates into the store required into the certificate parameters.